# html - how to scroll vertical in select box

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with  the select in html, i need a horizontal scroll bar to user see all the text.

What i have:

[image]

What i need:
[image]

My code:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select size="12" class="form-control">
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option><option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option><option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option><option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
</select>
```

Comment: where is your CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**overflow-x and overflow-y**

The overflow-x and overflow-y properties specifies whether to change the overflow of content just horizontally or vertically (or both):

`overflow-x` specifies what to do with the left/right edges of the content.

`overflow-y` specifies what to do with the top/bottom edges of the content.

```css
select{
overflow-x:auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select size="12" class="form-control">
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This work in CHROME and FIREFOX, but don't work in IE... any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Add `overflow-x: auto` or `scroll` to CSS

```css
select {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select size="12" class="form-control">
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
  <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
 select {
     overflow-x: scroll;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can set a fixed height and width first, then if it overflows that fixed width and height then a scroll-bar will appear. You can do this by setting [overflow-x and overflow-y to scroll.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_overflow-x)**

```css
.selectItems
{
  width: 800px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 600px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="selectItems">
  <select class="form-control">
    <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
    <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
    <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
    <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
    <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
    <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
    <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
    <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
    <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
    <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
    <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
    <option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add **overflow : auto** attribute  to the element

Answer (score 2):

All the provided answers have a serious usability problem: they allow either double vertical sidebars or vertical and horizontal sidebars, which make the element difficult to use on a number of devices.

Good user experience is to only allow one direction of scrolling per element and avoid double scrollbars:

### a) to allow only horizontal scrolling:

```css
select {
  overflow-x:auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```js
/*
 * sets select size to children + 1, 
 * to render vertical scrolling unnecessary:
 */
$(window).on('load', function(){
  $('select[size]').each((i,e) => {
    $(e).attr('size', $(e).children().length + 1);
  })
})
```

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){
  $('select[size]').each((i,e) => {
    $(e).attr('size', $(e).children().length + 1);
  })
})
```

```css
select {
  overflow-x:auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select size class="form-control">
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option><option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option><option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option><option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
</select>
```

### b) to allow only vertical scrolling (wrap options):

```css
select {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
option {
  white-space: initial;
}
```

```css
select {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
option {
  white-space: initial;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select size="12" class="form-control">
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
<option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option><option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option><option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option><option>Acompanhamento Orçamentário Ajustes orçamentário  - Visão Gestor e Segmentos/Acompanhamento de Segmentos e Produtos Ajustar o orçamento quando há alterações no orçamento vigente</option>
</select>
```